# Close Toast Message with messageData on hyperlink click - lwc

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, onclick, toast

I have a toast message in lwc that uses sticky mode (does not go away until the user click on close symbol) and also messageData (to add a hyperlink in the toast for the user to click on).

The thing is that I need the message to stay visible up **until the user clicks the hyperlink**, but the 'sticky' property does not recognize the click on the hyperlink (just the click on the close button 'x') and the toast remains visible after the actions of clicking on the hyperlink happen.

Is there any way I can make the toast aware of the click on the hyperlink, so the toast disappears when clicking on it? (as it does when clicking on the 'x').

```
const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                message: `this is a toast message bla bla bla {0}`,
                variant: 'success',
                mode: 'sticky',
                messageData : [
                    {
                        url,
                        label: 'click on the link and go to.. '
                    }
                ]
            })
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Thanks!